# How to avoid unhandled exception in Tkinter?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, exception, tkinter

I'm trying to exit my program when the user decides to close the Tkinter filedialog menu without selecting a file to open. However, although the program exits I keep getting the following message before it terminates:

`The debugged program raised the exception unhandled FileNotFoundError [Errno2] No such file or directory`

I thought the code I have below would handle something like that though, but maybe I am wrong? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
if root.fileName is None:
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: If `filedialog` doesn't get a filename, it returns an empty string `''`, not `None`. Try `if not root.filename:` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it doesn't `return` a filename (the user canceled the dialog), `filedialog` will `return` an empty string (`''`), not `None`. Use this instead:

```
if not root.fileName:
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have never used tkinter but it seems that even though no file was selected by the user the file dialog it is still trying to look for a file.
In general when handling exception you would place the relevant code in a try except block.
E.G. you may have to import the exception from tkinter for the below to work

```
   try:
    # code that can throw an exception
    if root.fileName is None:
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        pass
except FileNotFoundError:
    # add code on how you want the error handled
    pass
```

for more details on exception handling have a look at the doc's [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: The `FileNotFoundError` isn't produced by checking `root.fileName`, it'll be produced by some other part of the code that tries to use that filename and fails. The code is allowed to proceed past that check because `root.fileName` is never `None` - a canceled filename choice makes it the empty string, `''`.