# Logging progress/error on a tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have GUI built with tkInter like below.

My actual window is a bit more complex but I think this suffices for the question I have.

The window has `Entry`, 2 `Button`'s & a `scrollText` widget.

With the Browse button, user selects the file that she wants to process and clicking the `process` button call the `processFile` function to process the file.

What I want to do now is to print the 'progress' of in the `scrollText` widget. Nothing but the values of the `print` statements should appear in the `scrollText` widget one after the other. It need not be print statements, it be some other methods also (I do not know what other methods are possible).

Also, if there is a error. If you click the `process` button without selecting the file for example, the program encounters an error and stops. That error also needs to be shown in the `scrollText` widget.

How do I accomplish this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import pandas as pd


root=tk.Tk() # create a window within which all buttons and fileds are located
root.geometry('700x300') #defien the sixe of the window

def quit_me():
    """Function to end the process when 'x' is clicked"""
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

def browsefunc(entry):
    """Function to browse the file & set the browsed file path to the
    entry box in the GUI"""
    browsedFile =tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("text files","*.txt"),("All files","*.*")))
    if not browsedFile: #if cancel for pressed instead of selectign a file
        pass
    else: #if the file was seelcted
        entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, browsedFile)

def processFile(fileToProcess):
    df = pd.read_csv(fileToProcess, header=None, sep=';')
    print('df created...')
    print('df processes...')
    print('df processessing complete...')
    return df


fileNameEntry=tk.Entry(root)
fileNameEntry.place(x = 30, y = 30,width = 400, height = 20)
fileNameEntryButton =tk.Button(master=root,
                                 text="Browse",
                                 command=lambda: browsefunc(fileNameEntry))
fileNameEntryButton.place(x = 460, y = 30, width = 45, height = 20)

executeButton =tk.Button(master=root,
                                 text="Process",
                                 fg="#45ad61",
                                 command= lambda: processFile(fileNameEntry.get()))
executeButton.place(x = 400, y = 60, width = 150, height = 25)


progressWindow = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root,
                      bg='white',
                      relief="groove")
progressWindow.place(x = 30, y = 100 ,height=100,width=600,)


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit_me)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe it will help you - "Long-running task in Tkinter" <https://zetcode.com/articles/tkinterlongruntask/#:~:text=Tkinter%20uses%20a%20single%2Dthreaded,user%20considers%20the%20application%20unresponsive.>. tkinter.filedialog error handling - <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395360/how-to-avoid-unhandled-exception-in-tkinter>.

Comment: This did not help me. Thanks for the suggestions though